# Angular trying to reset the form

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create an application using Angular 4.
Trying to implement reset feature on my html form.

In my **app.component.html** file I gave form tag like.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<tr>
<th>LEVEL Name 1<br>level 1<br> <button (click)="myForm.reset();">clear</button> &nbsp; <a href="">Delete</a></th>
<th>IN Network</th></tr>
```

In my **app.component.ts** file my code for `onSubmit` function is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';

 onSubmit() {
    console.log("Form Cleared!");
  }
}
```

Now it does not reflect any error in code, but while I run my project on cmd by doing `ng serve`, In my browser `localhost://4200` nothing is displayed. When I press <kbd>F12</kbd>. It gives me below error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("<!--The content       below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->

<form [ERROR ->]#myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<h1>Provider Network Setup</h1>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:6
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part      of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

```
      [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</form>"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@91:0
    at syntaxError (webpack-      internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:706)
at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24882)
at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34835)
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34810)
at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34711)
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34711)
at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34581)
at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:695)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34580)
```

Can someone please guide here. TIA

Comment: Did you add the  `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms` to your imports?

Comment: Added now. The error got resolved. Webpage is getting displayed at localhost:4200 but the reset function is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
<form #myForm name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<tr>
<th>LEVEL Name 1<br>level 1<br> <button (click)="onSubmit()">clear</button> &nbsp; <a href="">Delete</a></th>
<th>IN Network</th></tr>
</form>
```

In our onSubmit we can say:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';
 @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: ElementRef;

  onSubmit() {
        this.myForm.reset();
    }

}
```

Also make sure your importing the forms module.

Comment: In app.component.ts file  it throws me an error "Property 'myForm' does not exist on type 'AppComponent' ".

Comment: @RuchitaJ, you need to grab myForm with a ViewChild

Comment: @Kai can you please elaborate.

Comment: I am trying to use "@ViewChild('frm') form;" but where exactly will it come can you pls advise on this.

Comment: Added viewchild into answer